# My dataset is huge and I don't know how to make figures with the data as it is

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, figure, rna-seq

I have RNAseq data for a Time-course experiment (6 time points) and involves tens of thousands of genes. 
I have used the Filter program on Tidyverse to find genes that fit certain criteria (reference genes for qPCR), but I don't know how to make this data into a figure easily. Right now, I'd have to change the format of the dataset completely, but that would take so much time to be impractical.

The goal is just to have a graph for each gene that shows the change in expression over time for each condition (different leaf pairs and droughted/well-watered). I have done this for some in Excel but would like a quicker way to do it.

The dataset is set out like this:

```
[1] "gene.id"                    "LP1.2.02:00.WW"             "LP1.2.02:00.WW_1"           "LP1.2.02:00.WW_2"          
 [5] "LP1.2.06:00.WW"             "LP1.2.06:00.WW_1"           "LP1.2.06:00.WW_2"           "LP1.2.10:00.WW"            
 [9] "LP1.2.10:00.WW_1"           "LP1.2.10:00.WW_2"           "LP1.2.14:00.WW"             "LP1.2.14:00.WW_1"          
[13] "LP1.2.14:00.WW_2"           "LP1.2.18:00.WW"             "LP1.2.18:00.WW_1"           "LP1.2.18:00.WW_2"          
[17] "LP1.2.22:00.WW"             "LP1.2.22:00.WW_1"           "LP1.2.22:00.WW_2"           "LP3.4.5.02:00.WW"          
[21] "LP3.4.5.02:00.WW_1"         "LP3.4.5.02:00.WW_2"         "LP3.4.5.06:00.WW"           "LP3.4.5.06:00.WW_1"        
[25] "LP3.4.5.06:00.WW_2"         "LP3.4.5.10:00.WW"           "LP3.4.5.10:00.WW_1"         "LP3.4.5.10:00.WW_2"        
[29] "LP3.4.5.14:00.WW"           "LP3.4.5.14:00.WW_1"         "LP3.4.5.14:00.WW_2"         "LP3.4.5.18:00.WW"          
[33] "LP3.4.5.18:00.WW_1"         "LP3.4.5.18:00.WW_2"         "LP3.4.5.22:00.WW"           "LP3.4.5.22:00.WW_1"        
[37] "LP3.4.5.22:00.WW_2"         "LP1.2.02:00.Drought"        "LP1.2.02:00.Drought_1"      "LP1.2.02:00.Drought_2"     
[41] "LP1.2.06:00.Drought"        "LP1.2.06:00.Drought_1"      "LP1.2.06:00.Drought_2"      "LP1.2.10:00.Drought"       
[45] "LP1.2.10:00.Drought_1"      "LP1.2.10:00.Drought_2"      "LP1.2.14:00.Drought"        "LP1.2.14:00.Drought_1"     
[49] "LP1.2.14:00.Drought_2"      "LP1.2.18:00.Drought"        "LP1.2.18:00.Drought_1"      "LP1.2.18:00.Drought_2"     
[53] "LP1.2.22:00.Drought"        "LP1.2.22:00.Drought_1"      "LP1.2.22:00.Drought_2"      "LP3.4.5.02:00.Drought"     
[57] "LP3.4.5.02:00.Drought_1"    "LP3.4.5.02:00.Drought_2"    "LP3.4.5.06:00.Drought"      "LP3.4.5.06:00.Drought_1"   
[61] "LP3.4.5.06:00.Drought_2"    "LP3.4.5.10:00.Drought"      "LP3.4.5.10:00.Drought_1"    "LP3.4.5.10:00.Drought_2"   
[65] "LP3.4.5.14:00.Drought"      "LP3.4.5.14:00.Drought_1"    "LP3.4.5.14:00.Drought_2"    "LP3.4.5.18:00.Drought"     
[69] "LP3.4.5.18:00.Drought_1"    "LP3.4.5.18:00.Drought_2"    "LP3.4.5.22:00.Drought."     "LP3.4.5.22:00.Drought"     
[73] "LP3.4.5.22:00.Drought_1"    "X74"                        "LP1.2.02:00.WW.mean"        "LP1.2.06:00.WW.mean"       
[77] "LP1.2.10:00.WW.mean"        "LP1.2.14:00.WW.mean"        "LP1.2.18:00.WW.mean"        "LP1.2.22:00.WW.mean"       
[81] "LP1.2.02:00.drought.mean"   "LP1.2.06:00.drought.mean"   "LP1.2.10:00.drought.mean"   "LP1.2.14:00.drought.mean"  
[85] "LP1.2.18:00.drought.mean"   "LP1.2.22:00.drought.mean"   "LP3.4.5.02:00.WW.mean"      "LP3.4.5.06:00.WW.mean"     
[89] "LP3.4.5.10:00.WW.mean"      "LP3.4.5.14:00.WW.mean"      "LP3.4.5.18:00.WW.mean"      "LP3.4.5.22:00.WW.mean"     
[93] "LP3.4.5.02:00.drought.mean" "LP3.4.5.06:00.drought.mean" "LP3.4.5.10:00.drought.mean" "LP3.4.5.14:00.drought.mean"
[97] "LP3.4.5.18:00.drought.mean" "LP3.4.5.22:00.drought.mean"
```

It's a lot of headings, and as you can see from the titles, they contain the time, leaf pairs and condition. So, I'm not sure how to translate this into an x~y graph.

I've had several thoughts including trying to divide conditions into different subsets (LP1.2. WW/ LP.1.2.D/LP3.4.5.WW/LP.3.4.5.D) and making a subset for Time (02:00, 06:00, etc.) and trying to make a graph for that.

```
#make subset for the time points 
    Time <- c("02:00", "06:00", "10:00", "14:00", "18:00", "22:00")


#make subsets for each condition (LP1.2. WW/ LP.1.2.D/LP3.4.5.WW/LP.3.4.5.D)
    LP1.2.WW.mean <- as.matrix(KG_graph_data[c( "LP1.2.02:00.WW.mean",
                      "LP1.2.06:00.WW.mean",
                      "LP1.2.10:00.WW.mean", 
                      "LP1.2.14:00.WW.mean", 
                      "LP1.2.18:00.WW.mean",
                      "LP1.2.22:00.WW.mean",
                      "gene.id")])
    LP.1.2.D.mean <- 
    as.matrix(KG_graph_data[c("LP1.2.02:00.drought.mean",
                                       "LP1.2.06:00.drought.mean",
                                       "LP1.2.10:00.drought.mean",
                                       "LP1.2.14:00.drought.mean",
                                       "LP1.2.18:00.drought.mean",
                                       "LP1.2.22:00.drought.mean",
                                       "gene.id")])
    LP345.WW.mean <- as.matrix((KG_graph_data[c("LP3.4.5.02:00.WW.mean",
                                        "LP3.4.5.06:00.WW.mean",
                                        "LP3.4.5.10:00.WW.mean",
                                        "LP3.4.5.14:00.WW.mean",
                                        "LP3.4.5.18:00.WW.mean",
                                        "LP3.4.5.22:00.WW.mean",
                                        "gene.id")]))
    LP345.D.mean <- 
   as.matrix(KG_graph_data[c("LP3.4.5.02:00.drought.mean",
                                      "LP3.4.5.06:00.drought.mean",
                                      "LP3.4.5.10:00.drought.mean",
                                      "LP3.4.5.14:00.drought.mean",
                                      "LP3.4.5.18:00.drought.mean",
                                      "LP3.4.5.22:00.drought.mean",
                                      "gene.id")])
```

I tried extracting a particular gene from each matrix to then perhaps plot a graph from but it only worked when it was from one matrix and even then, the table contained no data.

```
Total_KgGene007565 <- subset(LP1.2.WW.mean, "gene.id"=="KgGene007565",
                         LP.1.2.D.mean, "gene.id"=="KgGene007565",
                         LP345.WW.mean, "gene.id"=="KgGene007565",
                         LP345.D.mean, "gene.id"="KgGene007565")
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here or if this was the wrong way to approach this.

Comment: It depends on what you want to show with the graph. If you state that it is easier to help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you thought to use something like [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to reduce the numbers of columns? If it make sense for your goals.

Comment: You might find that posting this with the `data-visualization` tag over on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) gets a better response, as that's the Statistics 'bit' of Stack Exchange.

Comment: if you need to show changes in gene expression you can plot an heatmap with ggplot2 for instance or other package